# Four boxes with black and white pearls and a posteriori probabilities.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Boxes $S = \{A, B, C, D\}$ contain black $B$ and white $W$ pearls. Here are the counts:

$A = \{2\cdot W, 3\cdot B \}$

$B = \{1\cdot W, 3\cdot B \}$

$C = \{2\cdot W, 1\cdot B \}$

$D = \{3\cdot W, 1\cdot B \}$

Rules of the game: We get a pearl out of $A$ and put it in $B$, then out of $B$ into $C$ and then out of $C$ into $D$. One decides to get out the pearl out of the box $D$ and we all see the pearl that got out is white $W$.

**What is the probability that we have moved a black pearl out of the box $B$ into $C$?**

I have calculated all the conditional probabilities but I have a problem of understanding what exactly changes in the chain and how it affects the desired value of probability.

What I'm aware is that the a posteriori probabilities of hypothesis change and I guess the value of solution is one of these but I really can't figure out which.

Solution: $\frac{12}{17}$, have no idea how to get that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the numbers of possibilities for the various sequences ending in $W$:

$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
WWWW&2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4=48\\
BWWW&3\cdot1\cdot3\cdot4=36\\
WBWW&2\cdot3\cdot2\cdot4=48\\
BBWW&3\cdot4\cdot2\cdot4=96\\
WWBW&2\cdot2\cdot1\cdot3=12\\
BWBW&3\cdot1\cdot1\cdot3=9\\
WBBW&2\cdot3\cdot2\cdot3=36\\
BBBW&3\cdot4\cdot2\cdot3=72
\end{array}
$$

The total is $357$, and the total for the sequences with $B$ in the second slot is $252$, so the probability is $252/357=12/17$.

Comment: Is there any way to do it with Bayes and law of total probability? Perhaps the right question is, would it be any shorter than this clear answer?

Comment: @Leolinus: Not that I know.